# Могу ли я использовать Paho (EPL) для коммерческого проекта и НЕ раскрывать исходный код проекта?

Tags: android, библиотеки, лицензирование, opensource, зависимости

Мой проект предполагает работу с датчиками по протоколу MQTT. Могу ли я использовать библиотеку [Eclipse Paho](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java) (лицензированную под [EPL](http://www.dataved.ru/2011/03/eclipse-public-license-10.html)) для коммерческого проекта и НЕ раскрывать исходный код этого проекта? Я не собираюсь вносить изменения в код Paho, а хочу только использовать его в качестве библиотеки в приложении для Android. Мне не удалось найти точный ответ в интернете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, я написал письмо в Eclipse Foundation, и вот что мне ответили:

> I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice. You should seek legal advice from your own lawyer.
>   The EPL-2.0 FAQ's section on [derivative works](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/faq.php#h.dywt3xhx2jg) provides the Eclipse Foundation's view on the matter. 
>   The short version is that the **Eclipse Foundation does not consider linking with EPL content to be a derivative work and so you are not required to disclose your source code**.

Вкратце: в пунктах 5.2 и 5.3 их FAQ говорится, что вы можете свободно линковаться с EPL-софтом, и это не сделает вашу программу «производной» от него, т.е. раскрывать свои исходники не придётся. Т.е., я так понимаю, в качестве библиотеки можно свободно использовать.